# How do I add external source of gtfs data to transit api?

Tags: here-api

I'm planning to use the ability of here technologies for public transport routing and the visibility of traffic. My question is how to add external data sources for gtfs data. The current gtfs data doesn't cover a wider area and I want to include this area for calculation of routing for public transport.

Answer (score 0):

Specific library support for conversion of GTFS data for map rendering is not available, however data import is feasible via custom location extension.

Please find the reference for CLE below

developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/dev_guide/topics/custom-location-extensions-2.html